# Slick carousel center class not working when going from last item to first item

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

I a'm trying to make a carousel of (infinity) pictures with the Slick carousel jquery plugin, where all the pictures have opacity sat to 0.5 except the one currently in center, which should be set to 1.0 with a 1 second transition

I have made the following code:

The HTML:

```
<div id="pics">
            <div class="img">
                <div class="img_overlay">
                    <img src="https://bloximages.chicago2.vip.townnews.com/billingsgazette.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/c/a5/ca5baefc-d922-54e1-9429-abd16a353bce/59cced6868919.image.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img">
                <div class="img_overlay">
                    <img src="https://bloximages.chicago2.vip.townnews.com/billingsgazette.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/c/a5/ca5baefc-d922-54e1-9429-abd16a353bce/59cced6868919.image.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="img">
                <div class="img_overlay">
                    <img src="https://bloximages.chicago2.vip.townnews.com/billingsgazette.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/c/a5/ca5baefc-d922-54e1-9429-abd16a353bce/59cced6868919.image.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    *, html{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #pics{
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #282828;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #pics .img{
      display: inline-block;
      height: 500px;
      width: auto;
    }
    .img_overlay{
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    #pics .slick-dots{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
        top: -50px;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .slick-center .img_overlay{
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    #pics .img img{
        height: 500px;
        width: auto;
    }
    #pics .slick-prev, #billeder .slick-next{
        display: none !important;
    }
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pics').slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 1400,
            centerMode: true,
            variableWidth: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 1500,
            arrows: false
        });
    });
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jgfrs331/5/

This works fine, except when it goes from the last picture to the next picture (The next picture is really the first picture being showed again). I have inspected the code and i can see the class "slick-active" is first being correctly sat after the transition for the sliding effect is done, but only when it goes from last to the first picture, at all other times it is sat as soon as the sliding-transition is starting. I have struggled with this for hours, any advice is very apriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive got some help and found a solution by adding this JS and CSS:

CSS:

```
.img_overlay1{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition: 1s;
}
.img_overlay2{
    opacity: 0.3 !important;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

And JS:

```
$('#pics').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    $('.img').find('div:first-child').removeClass('img_overlay2');
    $('.img').find('div:first-child').removeClass('img_overlay1');
    if (nextSlide == 0) {
        $('.img').each(function () {
            obj = $(this);
            if (obj.data('slick-index') == currentSlide + 1) {
                obj.find('div:first-child').addClass('img_overlay1');
            }
            if (obj.data('slick-index') == currentSlide + 2) {
                obj.find('div:first-child').addClass('img_overlay2');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#pics').removeClass('slick-center');
    }
});
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jgfrs331/231/