# Slick Carousel: Hidden Content is not working on last and first item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Understand there are some similar topics such as this: [Slick carousel center class not working when going from last item to first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649119/slick-carousel-center-class-not-working-when-going-from-last-item-to-first-item)

I have tried, it's still not working on my code. Each of my item can be displayed in the middle and the rest of items are hidden. Except the last and first item. Please click on "item 8" and "item 1" below to understand what I mean.

I really need help on this, hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Please!

```js
$('.slick-wrap').slick({
      dots: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      infinite: true,
      arrows: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '30px',
      responsive: {
          600: {
              items: 2
          }
      }
 });


    $('.slick-wrap').on('init', function(event, slick){
        var carouselTexts = $(".slick-item .cont-hide");
        var idx = $(event.target).find('.slick-list .slick-center').index();
        carouselTexts.eq(idx).css('visibility', 'visible');
    });

    //display and hide the content
    $('.slick-item').on('click', function() {
        var carouselTexts = $(".slick-item .cont-hide");
        var clickedNum = $(".slick-item").index(this);

        carouselTexts.not(clickedNum).css('visibility', 'hidden')
        carouselTexts.eq(clickedNum).css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
```

```css
.slick-section{
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
.slick-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slick-wrap{
    margin: 0 -10px;
}
.slick-item{
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.slick-dots {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 25px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 .slick-dots li {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
 }

 .slick-active button{
     background: #ccc;
 }
 
.cont-hide{ visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class="slick-section">
  <div class="slick-container">
    <div class="slick-wrap">
        <div class="slick-item">1 <div class="main-panel cont-hide">test 1</div></div>
        <div class="slick-item">2 <div class="main-panel cont-hide">test 2</div></div>
        <div class="slick-item">3 <div class="main-panel cont-hide">test 3</div></div>
        <div class="slick-item">4 <div class="main-panel cont-hide">test 4</div></div>
        <div class="slick-item">5 <div class="main-panel cont-hide">test 5</div></div>
        <div class="slick-item">6 <div class="main-panel cont-hide">test 6</div></div>
        <div class="slick-item">7 <div class="main-panel cont-hide">test 7</div></div>
        <div class="slick-item">8 <div class="main-panel cont-hide">test 8</div></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.slick-item').on('click', function() {
        var carouselTexts = $(".slick-item .main-panel");
        var clickedNum = $(".slick-item").index(this);

    $('.slick-item .main-panel').each(function(i, obj) {
        jQuery(this).css('display', 'none');
    });

    jQuery(this).children('.main-panel').attr('style','display: block');
});

$('.slick-wrap').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
    var elt = slick.$slides.get(currentSlide);
    //console.log(elt);
    
    var elements = $(elt);
    var found = $('.main-panel', elements);
    found.attr('style','display: block');
    found.removeClass("cont-hide");
    
    var currentIndex = $(elt).data('slick-index');
});
```